# Keeps reading the first line of file

Tags: c, file, scanf

The program writes a `int` and a `string` in the same line of a file. I then need to read that `int` and `string` and assign to some variable. I've managed to write the data on the file as supposed, but when i try to read and store it, it seems that i'm either **only** read the first line over and over, or, i'm storing in the wrong way.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct cliente {
    char nome[50];
    int nif;
};

int main(void) {
    FILE * fptr;
    int i = 0;
    int quantidade = 0;
    int j = 0;

    fptr = fopen("clientedata", "w");

    if (fptr != NULL) {
        printf("File created successfully!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failed to create the file.\n");
        // exit status for OS that an error occured
        return -1;
    }
    printf("insira a quantidade: ");
    scanf("%d", & quantidade);
    struct cliente client[quantidade];

    for (i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
        fptr = fopen("clientedata", "a");
        printf("Enter clientedata name: ");
        scanf(" %[^\t\n]c", client[i].nome);
        printf("Enter clientedata NIF: ");
        scanf("%d", & client[i].nif);
        if (i == 0) {
            fprintf(fptr, "%d %s", client[i].nif, client[i].nome);
        } else fprintf(fptr, "\n%d %s", client[i].nif, client[i].nome);
        fclose(fptr);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < quantidade; j++) {

        fptr = fopen("clientedata", "r");
        fscanf(fptr, "%d %s", & client[j].nif, client[j].nome);
        printf("NIF: %d\n", client[j].nif);
        printf("nome: %s\n", client[j].nome);
        fclose(fptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output from the code and file:[Code and File Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAr3e.png)

Comment: `fptr = fopen("clientedata", "a");` You already have the file open, why are you calling `fopen` again? Remove that line and move `fclose(fptr);` to after the loop.

Comment: Same in the read loop. Open once before the loop and close after loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  Yes ! removing the fopen and fclose from the for loop and writing before and after the loop solved the problem ! Thank you.

Comment: Always check the return value of functions like `fscanf()` and `scanf()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes !
removing the `fopen` and `fclose` from the `for` loop and writing before and after the loop solved the problem ! Thank you!